# Creating Array for PDO Execute Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to dynamically create an array for the execute portion of a PDO insert. My working code includes text like this:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
  ':fname' => $_POST['fname'],
  ':lname' => $_POST['lname'],
  ':email' => $_POST['email']
));
```

My first attempt at creating an array:

```
$insert_execute = array();
foreach ($values as $column => $value) {
  array_push($insert_execute, ":" . $column . " => " . "'".$value."'");
}
```

But when I try to execute I get a PDO error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

And when I print the result, there is an additional parameter:

```
Array
(
  [0] => fname => 'Test Name'
  [1] => lname => 'Test Last'
  [2] => email => 'test@email.com'
)
```

How can I modify the array_push to remove the [0], [1], [2] etc. in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overly complicating the matter. You already have an associative array of parameter names to values so you can simply use that

```
$stmt->execute($values);
```

The colon prefix (`:`) on the parameter names in the array is optional. If it's not there, the PDO extension will add it automatically.

Comment: I was going to say, you should post that as the answer - I was over-complicating it as you gathered, I ended up just using $stmt->execute($_POST); and it was good to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Lauren Just be careful using `$_POST` as you cannot control what is in it.

Comment: I'm pulling it from an AJAX serialized array... does this undo the security measures that PDO offers?

Comment: @Lauren No, but any unexpected POST parameters will cause PDO to trigger an error / exception

Answer (score 1):

You're building, and pushing, strings onto that array. `=>` shouldn't be part of what you're inserting -- it's just for initialization.

What you mean to say:

```
foreach ($values as $column => $value) {
  $insert_execute[":$column"] = $value;
}
```